# Can an immersion globally be a smooth embedding?

Tags: general-topology, differential-topology, smooth-manifolds

I have a question about immersions and smooth embeddings which i couldnt find an answer for.

I know that

1. an immersion is locally a smooth embedding.
2. a smooth embedding is an injective immersion which is also a
       topological embedding.

**My question:** Let's say i have an injective immersion $f:M \to N$ for every point $p$ of $M$ between two smooth manifolds $M, N$ with $\dim N\le \dim N$. Does that mean that $f$ is not only locally a smooth embedding but globally?

I'd love to get behind the relation between 1. and 2.

**On a slightly more general note:** If i have a function $f:M \to N$ which is a smooth embedding, what exactly does that tell me? (geometrically) For reference, whenever i have a diffeomorphism, i know that both manifolds are "basically the same shape" roughyl speaking. How do i need to think about embeddings in these regards?

Thanks you very much!

Comment: I explain two examples of injective immersions which fail to be embeddings in my answer here: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1366711/68356. I think this would answer your first question at least :)

Comment: For your more general question: if $f$ is a smooth embedding, then its image is a submanifold of the target. And $f$ coincides with the induced inclusion map. At least, up to some self-diffeomorphism, which it doesn’t really make sense to worry about it in general.

Comment: Hello @john. thank you very much. Regarding my first question: what if my injective immersion is a topological embedding of $M$ into $N$? Does that mean, that my immersion is globally a smooth embedding? I'm trying to understand the relation between "local embedding" vs "global embedding" (if the latter exist)

Comment: Yes, if you have an injective immersion which is a topological embedding, then it is a smooth embedding. This should pretty much be the definition of the latter. It tells you that the difference between a local smooth embedding and a global smooth embedding is topological, which perhaps is the statement you were after?

Comment: i think that clarifies it! thank you very much john. happy holidays to you.

Comment: Great! Thanks, and you!